# ReadOnly vs Property within Assembly Question/Conundrum

Tags: .net, assemblies, properties, internal

How can I make a Property "ReadOnly" outside the Assembly (DLL) for people using the DLL but still be able to populate that property from within the assembly for them to read?

For example, if I have a **Transaction** object that needs to populate a property in a **Document** object (which is a child class of the **Transaction** class) when something happens in the **Transaction** object, but I just want to developer using my DLL to only be able to read that property and not change it (it should only be changed from within the DLL itself).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C#

```
public object MyProp {
   get { return val; }
   internal set { val = value; }
}
```

VB

```
Public Property MyProp As Object
   Get
      Return StoredVal
   End Get
   Friend Set(ByVal value As Object) 
      StoredVal = value
   End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using C# you can have different access modifiers on the `get` and `set`, e.g. the following should achieve what you want:

```
public int MyProp { get; internal set; }
```

VB.NET also has this capability: http://weblogs.asp.net/pwilson/archive/2003/10/28/34333.aspx

Answer (score 3):

C#

```
public bool MyProp {get; internal set;} //Uses "Automatic Property" sytax
```

VB

```
private _MyProp as Boolean
Public Property MyProp as Boolean
   Get
      Return True
   End Get
   Friend Set(ByVal value as Boolean)
      _MyProp = value
   End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

What language? In VB you mark the setter as Friend, in C# you use internal.